# How to put several columns in one row and leave one row empty?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I want my text to look like this:

[image: Text]

My code so far:

```
{\mdseries Topic}: &
    \begin{multicols}{2}    
            \item TopicA
            \item TopicB
            \item TopicC
            \item[] Good
            \item[] Very Good
            \item[] Very Good
    \end{multicols}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand what you're ultimate typesetting objective is. For sure, a simple `tabular` environments lets you re-create the screenshot you posted:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Topic: & TopicA & Good \\
       & TopicB & Very Good \\
       & TopicC & Very Good
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```